# Data From REST API In Azure

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-data-factory

I have implemented REST API calls using a standalone c# console application. The API returns JSON which i'm deserializing and then storing it in the database. 
Now i want to implement the entire logic in Azure platform so that it can invoked by passing start date and an end date and store location (it should run for three location) Below is the code:

```
static void Main()
    {


        MakeInventoryRequest();

    }

    static async void MakeInventoryRequest()
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var queryString = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Empty);

            // Request headers
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "5051fx6yyy124hhfyuscf34f57ce9");


            // Request parameters

            queryString["query.locationNumbers"] = "4638";
            queryString["availableFromDate"] = "2019-01-01";
            queryString["availableToDate"] = "2019-03-07";


            var uri = "https://api-test.location.cloud/api/v1/inventory?" + queryString;

            using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, uri))
            using (var response = await client.SendAsync(request))
            {

                var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode == true)
                {
                    List<Inventory> l1 = DeserializeJsonFromStream<List<Inventory>>(stream);

                    InsertInventoryRecords(l1);
                }


                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode == false)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Error Response Code: " + response.StatusCode.ToString() + "Content is: " + response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Please suggest the best possible design using Azure components

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the information in hand I think you have multiple options , you need to find out which works for you the best . You can use Cloud service to  host the console app ( you will have to change it to worker role , Visual studio will help you to convert that ) . I am not sure about the load which you are expecting but you can always increase and decrease the instance and these can be deployed to different geographies .

I see that you are persisting the data , if you want to do that you can use many of the SQL offerings . For invoking the REST API you can also azure functions and ADF.

Please feel free to comment if you want any more details on the same.

Comment: Currently i'm directly writing the data to SQL Database after reading and  de-serializing the Json response from Rest API all using Azure Function through HttpTrigger. Do you think its a good approach. Will there be any time out issue if the volume of records is huge.

Comment: Yes it is a good way to do so. You can also have a look at "Azure Function Activity" for the same.

As for the timeout, the REST API connector supports a property httpRequestTimeout which is The timeout (the TimeSpan value) for the HTTP request to get a response. This value is the timeout to get a response, not the timeout to read response data. The default value is 00:01:40.